# WPF: When opening a new window and closing the current the whole application freezes

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets

I'm creating a client for a server I set up. The login and register menus seem to work smoothly and i can switch between windows pretty much seamlessly.

But, whenever I try to sign out from my main window the whole application freezes and doesn't  show the login screen like it's supposed to.

This is the sign-out function from the main menu:

```
private void Signout_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!checkConnection())
            {
                textMessage.Text = "Couldn't connect to host";
                return;
            }

            bool response;

            try
            { 
                response = m_client.signout();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
                return;
            }

            if (response)
            {
                LoginMenu lm = new LoginMenu();
                lm.Show();
                Close();
            }
            else
            {
                textMessage.Text = "Couldn't sign out";
            }
        }
```

Essentially when you sign out from the main menu the server removes the user from the connected users list and then closes the socket. The server side is working fine and i checked it with a console client.

The login menu then creates a new instance of "Client" and reconnects to the server. When i use the debugger it seems to be working fine. But when it finishes initializing the login screen the application just freezes.

My login Screen setup:

```
public partial class LoginMenu Window
    {
        private Client m_client;
        public LoginMenu()
        {
            string temp = "";
            try
            {
                m_client = new Client();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Couldn't connect to host");
                System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
            }
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

I included every single thing i thought might be relevant since I can't really find the source of the issue (also why i included several topics). After a few hours of unyielding google search this is all i can come up with...

Comment: After you `Show` the LoginMenu, you `Close` which window? The `MainWindow`?

Comment: @LegacyCode Yes, its the same as writing `this.Close();`

Comment: So you are closing the main window? Means `Application.Current.MainWindow` is `null`?

Comment: No, the window i'm closing is `Application.Current.MainMenu` although whether it's `null` or not i'm not sure. I'm assuming it is after using `Close`

Comment: So you have a window that is a menu... And the main window is which window?

Comment: @LegacyCode The `LoginMenu` is the `mainWindow`. I changed the names in my question so it will be obvious which window i'm opening.

Comment: The `LoginMenu` cannot be your MainWindow, because you are literally creating it in the `Signout_Click`. Check whats in `Application.Current.MainWindow`.

Comment: Perhaps i don't fully understand what MainWindow means. The first window that pops up when i open the application is the login menu which is the MainWindow (I only named it LoginMenu here for demonstration purposes). I switch many times between this window and different windows the same way i do here (between a signUp menu and login menu for example). Is there something I'm missing? Take in mind I'm new to c# since i learnt it over the weakend.

Comment: Set your `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` to all and run the program.

Comment: I still get the same result. this doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: That should catch any Exception happening, even the swallowed ones.

Comment: When you close the mainwindow, by default a wpf application shuts down. The mainwindow is whichever you show first. If you show LoginMenu first then is there still an instance of that hanging about somewhere? But you're instantiating another instance. 2 LoginMenus.  If you want to show one window at a time then make this a single window app. Mainwindow and nothing else. Change the content of mainwindow to login or whatever. Preferably using viewmodel first to template out a viewmodel into a usercontrol.